# Where is Apostol's Mathematical Analysis being used?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

I have noticed that Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, third edition, is being used at many universities in the US.

I'm wondering which of the world's top ranked universities, especially those  who contribute their course contents as OCW, are using *Mathematical Analysis* by Tom M. Apostol, second edition, for their undergrad or postgrad mathematical analysis courses?

Comment: Caltech. At least in my day - maybe still.

Comment: UC Berkeley also.